# Count occurrences of a sub string in a String

Tags: c++, string, substring

First of all, I know there are many duplicates of this question but I have tried and tried and non have been able to solve my issue.

I have the following string

```
string s = "asdfqasdfp";
```

I need to loop through the string and find which sub string appears more than once. so in this case its

```
asdf
```

I have made the following code but I do not know why it doesn't work. I start from the full string and go down one at a time. I should get occurence value of 2.

```
int t = s.length();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    string str = s.substr(0, t);
    int occurence = 0;
    size_t start = 0;
        while ((start = s.find(str, start)) != string::npos) {
            ++occurence;
            start += str.length();
        }
        if (occurence > 1) {
            cout << occurence;
        }
        else {
            --t;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I only want the largest substring that the string contains, in this case

> "asdf"

Comment: First, you need to identify all possible substrings in the input string. This cannot be done with a single loop. (Try to print them out to see that it works.) Second, for each substring, check for its number of occurrences. This is a naive approach and likely can be improved, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: Sorry if it is naive, I am very new to cpp and have been struggling with it.

Comment: With "naive" I was referring to my suggested approach, not to your code (which does not work).

Comment: Note that there are many substrings with multiple occurrences in `"asdfqasdfp"`. Not only `"asdf"`, but also `"a"`, `"s"`, ..., `"sdf"`. If you don't want them all, please, edit the question to specify what you really want to do.

Comment: Question has been editied to clarify what I want

Comment: You probably just need to wrap the for loop in `while (t  > 1)`, and limit the i loop to `<= s.length() - t` (I think) so that you always take t characters. And then just track the maximum, as you've updated.

Comment: @rex You obviously consider only substrings that start at the beginning of the input string (`s.substr(0, t);`). Is this what you want? What if the input string is `"xasdfqasdfp"`?

Comment: Oh good spot: I'd read that as `s.substr(i, t)`. Which I think is what you wanted.

Comment: @Rup It definitely will not work just with `s.substr(i, t)`. [Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GGredK95ELYYSXtv).

Comment: @Dabiel if s.substr(i, t) doesn't work what can i change it to?

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, I meant on top of the t loop from my other comment.

Comment: Your code is checking only for the substrings which are prefixes of `s`. For example, if `s = "abc"`, your code will check only for substrings `abc`, `ab` and `a`. A string of length `n` has `n(n+1)/2` substrings so you'll have to first calculate all those substrings and then calculate the occurrance of each substring individually.

Comment: @rex Do what I wrote in my very first comment. Have you tried it? Rup did that for you, but you may prefer do to this by yourself if you want to learn something.

Comment: @Daniel I did what Rup did for me and it provided a quick fix to my issue. However, I will be now attempting to do it your way so i can gain a better understanding. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your code, including Daniel's suggestions (thanks! [Daniel's demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lJs6rf3OLGVIqAdO))

```
for (size_t t = s.length(); t >= 1; --t) {
    for (size_t i = 0; (i + t) <= s.length(); i++) {
        std::string str = s.substr(i, t);
        size_t occurence = 0;
        size_t start = 0;
        while ((start = s.find(str, start)) != std::string::npos) {
            ++occurence;
            start += str.length();
        }
        if (occurence > 1) {
            std::cout << str << " " << occurence << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to

1. loop over t, and decrement it at the end of the i loop rather than inside
2. limit i to s.length() - t, so that there's always a t-length string to take as str
3. fix your substr to start at i not 0

You can also stop at the first time you find a duplicate, since this will be a largest duplicate (e.g. if there are two pairs of duplicates of length 4 it will find one of them, but it doesn't sound like you need both). You should also use size_t throughout as your integer type since that's what's used by the string functions here.

Comment: Note that: 1) You may start with `t=s.length()-1` (if the input string is non-empty). 2) You can end the whole searching the first time `(occurence>1)` is true. No reason to proceed further. 3) Why not simply `cout << str <<...`? 4) Change all `int` to `size_t`. [Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lJs6rf3OLGVIqAdO).

Comment: Oops, yes, I'd meant to edit out the .c_str(). Tested in Visual Studio and I'd left it in the default UTF-16 mode so was easier to type that. Yes, I agree with all your other suggestions, but this was meant as a minimal fix rather than a complete fix.

Answer (score -3):

Looks ok. Do you need an `<< endl;` to see output in your terminal?

Comment: Have you tried it? [It does not give a correct answer for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nYMwIrFnuKe3E3Oo).

Comment: `std::endl` does not make you _"see output in your terminal"_. It appends a newline sequence (usually `'\n'`, depends on the platform) and apply `std::flush` to immediately flush the buffer.